# Set input field in javascript not working when assigning html to js variable

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, razor

I have the following in cshtml - which retrieves an hidden div and opens dialogue box. but before that, i want to set the value of the inputs in jquery

```
<div id="js-exampleDiv" hidden>


     <form class="js-bootboxForm">
        <div class="form-group">
          @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Batch):
          <b><label class="ScannedBatch"></label></b>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Weight, new { @class = "mb-0" })
          <input type="text" id="ScannedWeightAdjust" class="ScannedWeightAdjust" />

        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Quantity, new { @class = "mb-0" })
          <input type="text" id="ScannedQuantityAdjust" class="ScannedQuantityAdjust" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Packs, new { @class = "mb-0" })
          <input type="text" id="ScannedPacksAdjust" class="ScannedPacksAdjust" />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

I am using a bootbox dialogue to get the html, and open the dialogue but i am trying to set the input fields but it does not set, whereas the labels do set. Here is the javascript:

```
  $('.ScannedWeightAdjust').val('ss');
  var bootboxHtml = $('#js-exampleDiv').html();
`  bootbox.alert(bootboxHtml, function (result) {
    console.log($('#ScannedWeightAdjust', '.js-bootboxForm').val());
    console.log($('#ScannedPacksAdjust', '.js-bootboxForm').val());
    console.log($('#ScannedQuantityAdjust', '.js-bootboxForm').val());
  });`
```

Comment: `val()` is only present for `input` and not for `label`.

Comment: Yes, i have an input with id = ScannedWeightAdjust and its not setting the value

Comment: change . to #: $('#ScannedWeightAdjust').val('ss');

Comment: @lanes123 - It seems like you are saying opposite. I mean you are able to set the val for input but not for label.

Comment: @random ScannedWeightAdjust is an input field, and it does not set the value of that input. if i change the control to a label - and use .text('ss') and then that works

Comment: @lanes123 - It seems like you are resetting it again to empty in this line `$('#ScannedWeightAdjust', '.js-bootboxForm').val()`. Could you please reproduce the issue? Why `id` and `class` have same name?